# Heroku node.js app crashing upon heroku open

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, redis

I have followed the 'Getting started with node.js' tutorial on Heroku with no issues until I try 'heroku open'. The heroku logs are as below:

```
2015-09-06T01:40:57.721184+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-06T01:41:03.369114+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-09-06T01:41:06.941642+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-06T01:41:06.941663+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-site@1.0.0 start /app
2015-09-06T01:41:06.941665+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2015-09-06T01:41:06.941666+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-06T01:41:12.745724+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:85
2015-09-06T01:41:12.745730+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2015-09-06T01:41:12.745731+00:00 app[web.1]:             ^
2015-09-06T01:41:12.745733+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
2015-09-06T01:41:12.745734+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisClient.on_error (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:185:24)
2015-09-06T01:41:12.745735+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:95:14)
2015-09-06T01:41:12.745736+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
2015-09-06T01:41:12.745737+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:459:14
2015-09-06T01:41:12.745739+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
2015-09-06T01:41:12.789099+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2015-09-06T01:41:12.782590+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-06T01:41:12.789353+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v0.12.7
2015-09-06T01:41:12.790048+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
2015-09-06T01:41:12.790211+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-09-06T01:41:12.790403+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! my-site@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2015-09-06T01:41:12.790668+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2015-09-06T01:41:12.790523+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2015-09-06T01:41:12.790800+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the my-site@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2015-09-06T01:41:12.791028+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the my-site package,
2015-09-06T01:41:12.791621+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2015-09-06T01:41:12.791492+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-09-06T01:41:12.791865+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2015-09-06T01:41:12.791747+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2015-09-06T01:41:12.791990+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-site
2015-09-06T01:41:12.792118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2015-09-06T01:41:12.739572+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on localhost: 6596
2015-09-06T01:41:12.794869+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-06T01:41:12.788632+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
2015-09-06T01:41:12.795086+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2015-09-06T01:41:12.795203+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-09-06T01:41:14.558203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-06T01:41:14.544183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-09-06T01:41:39+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.065 sample#load-avg-5m=0.055 sample#load-avg-15m=0.045 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=14101096kB sample#memory-cached=514208kB sample#memory-redis=294000bytes
2015-09-06T01:42:20+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.085 sample#load-avg-5m=0.06 sample#load-avg-15m=0.05 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=14101344kB sample#memory-cached=514208kB sample#memory-redis=294000bytes
2015-09-06T01:43:43+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.05 sample#load-avg-5m=0.06 sample#load-avg-15m=0.045 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=14101108kB sample#memory-cached=514208kB sample#memory-redis=294000bytes
2015-09-06T01:44:27+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.02 sample#load-avg-5m=0.05 sample#load-avg-15m=0.045 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=14101176kB sample#memory-cached=514212kB sample#memory-redis=294000bytes
2015-09-06T01:45:46+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.005 sample#load-avg-5m=0.04 sample#load-avg-15m=0.04 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=14101240kB sample#memory-cached=514212kB sample#memory-redis=294000bytes
2015-09-06T01:46:24+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.035 sample#load-avg-5m=0.04 sample#load-avg-15m=0.04 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15405664kB sample#memory-free=14100784kB sample#memory-cached=514212kB sample#memory-redis=294000bytes
```

The issue is with Redis with which I have no experience.

Redis Heroku is installed as an addon and everything works fine when running `npm start` on my local machine.

Has anyone encountered this before or have any ideas?

Comment: Is your redis server running ? redis-server on your terminal to start it

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a redis server running locally, but your Heroku instance isn't going to be able to connect to your local redis instance, and if you are using the same configs on the Heroku run, it will be looking for something on the same endpoint (I'm guessing 127.0.0.1 port 3000 or something).

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis

At Redis-to-Go you can get a free/nano plan you can test. 
http://redistogo.com/
and just connect remote.
That's an alternative to provisioning through Heroku, I think I verified that approach works some months ago.  It still should.

You can test Heroku apps locally under conditions closer to their deployed environment by using ~~`foreman start`~~ now `heroku local`
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local, 
and check out this on `process`
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile